# Как в Nim читать постоянный потоковый вывод?

Tags: shell, nim

Как в языке Nim обрабатывать ответ программ вроде tcpdump, которая работает параллельно с программой на Nim?

Comment: А что такое tpdump? И куда он отдаёт свой вывод? Если, судя по вопросу, в stdout/stderr, то уточните ещё раз вопрос - проблема у вас с чтением стандартных потоков, или с чтением вывода этой конкретной программы?

Comment: Добавьте тег nim.

Comment: @dunduk tcpdump - сниффер. Вывод льется непрерывным потоком в stdout. У меня нет проблем с чтением одиночного вывода. Есть проблемы с обработкой подобного постоянного вывода.

Comment: @antage репутация пока что слишком мала для добавления новых тегов)

Comment: @АртёмБадртдинов, ну так в цикле читайте по одной строке и обрабатывайте. В консоли запускайте так: `tcpdump | ./yourprogram`, и весь вывод `tcpdump` будет направлен на стандартный ввод вашей программы.

Answer (score 0):

ответ из комментария:

---

в цикле читайте по одной строке и обрабатывайте. В консоли запускайте так:

```
$ tcpdump ... | ./yourprogram
```

и весь вывод `tcpdump` будет направлен на стандартный ввод вашей программы.

Comment: Вопрос о том, как обрабатывать входной поток данных из stdin, а не о том, как запускать tcpdump совместно со своей программой, чтобы передавать ей данные в stdin.